# Adding Within Each Loop Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the below

```
$('.amount2').on("input", function() {
  var total = 0;
  var i = 0;
  $('#manifest-table25 .amount2').each(function() {

    total += $('#id_form-'+(i)+'-Amount').val();
    i++;
  })
  
  $('#id_InvoiceTotal').val(total);
});
```

What is confusing me is that when I enter the value 5 into the input I would expect for the total to equal 5, instead it shows on the UI as 05.  How do I remove the leading zero/any thoughts on what is causing it? It is an integerfield in the model not charfield.

Comment: Please make / add [mre] it is helping us help you, its faster for everyone if we don't have to write it our-self to test things out. Use `<>` button in editor to make a snippet. You will increase a chance for fast help by a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.val()` return a string.
You need to parse it into an integer or a float before doing some math:

```
$('.amount2').on("input", function() {
  var total = 0;
  var i = 0;
  $('#manifest-table25 .amount2').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($('#id_form-'+(i)+'-Amount').val());
    i++;
  })
  
  $('#id_InvoiceTotal').val(total);
});
```